# Cannot run unit tests on modules with dependencies on dojo 1.x using the Intern

Tags: dojo, intern

We are just starting out with getting some unit tests running in the Intern on our dojo-based project.

What happens is that when the intern tries to load the module under test's dependencies we get the following error:

```
/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:406
                match = mid.match(/^(.+?)\!(.*)$/);
                           ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null at getModule (/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:406:15) at mix.amd.vendor (/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:832:17) at /<path/to/dev/folder>/app/src/simplebuilding/model/ModelError.js:10:1
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:74:17)
    at Object.vm.runInThisContext (/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
    at /<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:762:8
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Here is my config file - I started by copying the example one, and adding the map section to the loader.

```
define({
    proxyPort: 9000,
    proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.41.0'
    },
    { browserName: 'chrome', version: '40', platform: [ 'OS X' ] }
    ],
    maxConcurrency: 3,
    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
    loader: {
    // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
    packages: [
      { name: 'dojo', location: 'src/dojo' },
      { name: 'dojox', location: 'src/dojox' },
      { name: 'dijit', location: 'src/dijit' },
      { name: 'app', location: 'src/app' },
      { name: 'tests', location: 'tests' }
    ],
    map: {
      '*': {
        'dojo' : 'dojo'
      },
      app : {
        'dojo' : 'dojo'
      },
      intern : {
        'dojo' : 'node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo'
      },
      'tests' : {
        'dojo' : 'dojo'
      }
    }
    },
    suites: [ 'tests/model/modelerror' ],
    functionalSuites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/functional' */ ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|test\-explore|node_modules)\//
});
```

The file under test has dependencies on dojo/_base/declare, dojo/_base/lang, and dojo/Stateful, and that is about it.

I created a dummy class to test where there were no dojo dependencies and it runs fine.

I've tried switching the loader to be the local dojo 1.10.3 version we have in our project, and that throws entirely different errors about not being able to find the intern (even if I give it a package definition in the config).  Those errors look like this:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/.bin/main.js']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/<path/to/dev/folder>/app/node_modules/.bin/main.js',
  syscall: 'open' }
```

Our project structure is pretty straight-forward:

```
root
|--src
   |--dojo (dijit/dojox/dgrid/etc)
   |--app
|--tests
   |--intern.js (config file)
```

I've tried several variations besides changing the loader, like trying to make sure the base-path is correct.  I've tried running it in Node 0.10.36, and 0.12.2.  But every time I debug this with node-inspector when it gets to load the module for my file under test and the mid is null, and jumping back up the stack trace it looks fine, but something is lost in the vm.runInThisContext() call, and the mid disappears by the time getModule() is called.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out - we had modules we were loading inside of our project that used an old style of the define() function.  We had moved from the old `define('my.module.namespace', ['deps'], function(deps){ ... });` to replacing the dot namespace for the module in the first argument with null.  We were doing this as a transitionary phase to removing that argument completely, but hadn't ever finished that transition.  This was causing the dojo2 loader to think the "id" of the module was null, and that was causing the loader to not find a Module ID.

This was a completely silly mistake on our part, and this will help us modernize to the updated signature for future-dojo-readiness.